# Problems with installing mongodb 5 on ubuntu 20.04 Focal

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I was trying to install mongodb on ubuntu 20.04 on vm.
When i keyed in this line and hit enter:

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-5.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

nothing happened. Why is that? 'OK' is supposed to be output but nothing came out whatsoever. Hence I wasn't be able to install mongodb successfully on ubuntu 20.04.
I followed instructions on [this site](https://www.cherryservers.com/blog/how-to-install-and-start-using-mongodb-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: What output should that generate if the key is already there?

Comment: Maybe you should follow better this site [Install MongoDB Community Edition on Ubuntu](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)